# MYSQL error 2006 when running an UPDATE based on condition in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I get mysql error 2006 (server gone away) when trying to run the following SQL query:

```
UPDATE user_items 
SET A = A + 1, B = B + 1 
WHERE uid IN 
(SELECT uid FROM user_achievements WHERE C >= 10)
```

I've heard that error 2006 happens when the queries are very heavy.

Would like some advice on how I could either the optimize the above query or bypass the error?

My database is running on MySQL 5.6.

Thanks.

Comment: try using a join instead of having a select statement in the where clause

Comment: Hi Adi, could you show me how this might be done? thanks.

Comment: I need more context to write the query, how are `user_items` and `user_achievements` related to each other? Does `user_items` have a `uid` which is also referenced in `user_achievements`?

Comment: Yes. They share the same values in the same column named "uid" in both tables. I imagine it could be somehow joined on user_items.uid = user_achievements.uid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the tables can reference each other with `uid`. You can try using join since subqueries can use up lot of resources, try something like this -

```
UPDATE user_items 
JOIN user_achievements ON user_items.uid = user_achievements.uid
SET user_items.A = user_items.A + 1, user_items.B = user_items.B + 1 
WHERE user_achievements.C >= 10;
```

Comment: This worked, thanks!